# First air-to-air missile illustration in a German pulp magazine published in 1909 or 1910

Tags: story-identification

In his regular column in *Galaxy*, [*For Your Information*](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v13n01_1956-11/page/n51) (v. 13, no. 1, p. 47-59; November 1956), Willy Ley wrote up several technological feats (e.g., television, tanks, remote manipulators) that were investigated in science fiction before they were made practical in reality. For one of them, the air-to-air missile, he recalled a German pulp magazine from "around 1909 or early 1910" whose cover art portrayed the weapon. Ley added that it resembled a German air-to-ground missile used in World War II, the [Henschel Hs-293](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henschel_Hs_293). He added, "I cannot illustrate it for the simple reason that I could not find files of that old magazine (more accurately, 'dime novel') in a library." This would seem to have historical significance. Can anyone recognize this long-lost magazine and post images of the cover and relevant text?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The magazine that printed stories about Captain Mors is [Der Luftpirat und sein lenkbares Luftschiff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Luftpirat_und_sein_lenkbares_Luftschiff) (The Air Pirate and His Steerable Airship). It was printed from 1908 to 1911, and was banned in 1916 as potentially giving away military secrets.

There is [a web site here that has summaries of all the issues](http://www.villa-galactica.de/luftpirat_1_bis_10.htm) - all 165 of them. Flicking through the covers I found issue 61 has this cover:

[image: Issue 61]

That does have a missile looking a bit like an Hs 293:

[image: Hs 293]

([picture from here](http://www.walterwerke.co.uk/missiles/hs293.htm))

Although to me it looks more like a [V1 flying bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-1_flying_bomb):

[image: V1 Flying Bomb]

Comment: Stunning. Thank you, John Rennie! "...banned in 1916 as potentially giving away military secrets": Indeed.

Comment: Incidentally, Willy Ley was born in 1906 and emigrated to Great Britain and then the United States in 1935, "carrying only his favorite books, a few changes of clothing and travel documentation" (Wikipedia article, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willy_Ley). What is the link to the website showing the 165 covers?

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron oops, I missed the link out of my answer. I have added it to my answer now.